# Create new Thread clear file and folder c#

Tags: c#, winforms, file, directory, del

I created a Thread to automatically delete files and folders in "C:\Classified Defects\data".
First I use timer to check disk space, if it is more than 80% then call delete function to run.
if it is less than 50% it will stop.Here I use the progressBar to show the size of the drive:

```
 [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, ControlThread = true)]
        private void timerCleanup_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long result, total, free, available;
            result = GetDiskFreeSpaceEx("C:", out available, out total, out free);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                long TotalGB = total / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
                long freeFB = free / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
                i = Convert.ToInt32(TotalGB - freeFB);
                CircleProgressBarDisk.Maximum = 100;
                Persent = Convert.ToInt32(i * 100 / TotalGB);
                lbPersion.Text = Persent.ToString() + "%";
                CircleProgressBarDisk.Value = Persent;
                if (Persent >= 80)
                {
                    Thread Cle = new Thread(Cleanup);//I created a new thread to call the Cleanup function
                    Cle.IsBackground = true;
                    string dirname = @"C:\ClassifiedDefects\data";
                    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dirname);
                     if (di.Exists)
                        {
                            CircleProgressBarDisk.Animated = true;
                            Cle.Start();
                            if (Persent <= 50)
                            {
                                Cle.Abort(1000);
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                          { lbFilename.Text = "Not found folder source!";}
                }
            }
        }
       private void Cleanup()
        {
            string dirname = @"C:\ClassifiedDefects\data";
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dirname);
            if (di.Exists)
            {
                if (DateTime.UtcNow - di.CreationTimeUtc < TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
                    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
                    {
                        file.Delete();
                        lbFilename.Text = (file.Name);
                    }
            }
            if (di.Exists)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
                {
                    dir.Delete(true);
                    lbFilename.Text = (dir.Name);
                }
            }
        }
```

The code works, but when running it takes up very high computer resources. To make the computer hang, please advise me: what is the best way to delete all files and folders most efficiently!

Comment: Doing work requires computer resources. If you want to use less resources, you need to do less work. Based on the incomplete code example above, I would guess that you've set your timer interval too short. You should **a)** use a reasonably long interval for the timer, and **b)** adjust the implementation so that if the code is currently still cleaning, it doesn't start another attempt at cleaning. If you need more advice than that, please fix your question so it includes a proper [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: The background `Thread` could be garbage collected before it finishes. To prevent that, keep a reference to the thread object as a class member variable.

Comment: Also, depending on how often `timerCleanup_Tick(...)` is called, the condition `if (Persent >= 80)` could be met multiple times, and each time it starts a new thread. So you will have multiple threads attempting to delete the same directory.

Comment: @Loathing: _"The background Thread could be garbage collected before it finishes"_ -- that's misleading at best. A `Thread` object will only be GC'ed if it's not reachable. If you have a reference to it, then by definition it's reachable. Whether the `Thread` object itself does or does remain reachable will have _no_ effect on the thread itself so the state of the `Thread` object is completely irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make life simpler, and only delete files over 7 days if the directory has grown beyond a predetermined size (disks fill up for other reasons; triggering a delete if the disk is over 80% may result in triggering a delete every Tick even when there is nothing to delete)

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){

    timer.Stop();

    try{
      var dir = new DirectoryInfo(PATH);
      dir.Create(); //ensure exists, no-op if it does 

      var files = dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

      int deleted = 0;
      if(files.Sum(f => f.Length) > MAX_DIR_SIZE){

        foreach(var file in files.Where(f=>f.CreationTime < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(DELETE_FILES_OVER_DAYS_AGE))
          try{ f.Delete(); deleted++; } catch(Exception e) { statusListBox.Items.Add($"{e.Message} - {f.FileName}");

        if(deleted == 0)
          statusListBox.Items.Add($"Dir size is above the {MAX_DIR_SIZE} threshold but all files within are younger than {DELETE_FILES_OVER_DAYS_AGE} days. Adjust the DELETE_FILES_OVER_DAYS_AGE setting");
      }

      var dirs = files.Select(f => f.DirectoryName.ToLower()).Distinct;
      var root = PATH.ToLower().TrimEnd(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);

      foreach(string d in dirs.Except(new [] { root }))

        try{ Directory.Delete(d); } //remove empties 
        catch(IOException) { } //ignore IO errors like "not empty"
        catch(Exception e) { 
          statusListBox.Items.Add($"{e.Message} - {f.FileName}");
        }

    } 
    finally{
      timer.Interval = 10*60*1000; //ten mins
      timer.Start();
    }

}
```

Just check that the logic for not deleting the root folder (select distinct file directories except the root) does successfully skip the root folder.